# Making pen and ink corrections on a UK visa form?

Tags: visas, uk, legal, applications

After printing out a UK visa form, can you cross out planned arrival date with a pen and write a new one?

Comment: Yes, very common.

Comment: So it doesn't effect ?

Comment: Not 'effect', 'affect'. And it doesn't affect anything. OK, as long as you don't make a dog's breakfast out of it.

Comment: If someone is struggling with 'affect/effect', the phrase 'dog's breakfast' might be lost on them... (he means 'a mess').

Answer (score 4):

Advice appears to suggest that as long as passport and visa applications are neat, very minor crossed out errors won't make any trouble;

> - Complete the form in capital letters with a black ballpoint pen
> - Write only within the white boxed areas
> - Leave other areas of the form blank.  Do not strike through or otherwise mark them
> - If you make minor mistakes you can black them out with a pen. Do not use correction fluid.

[Source - visacentral.co.uk](http://visacentral.co.uk/passport-application-guidelines)

These guidlines are similar for all similar applications - the most important point is **do not use correction fluid!**

[As suggested here,](https://www.keyvisathailand.com/what-if-i-make-a-mistake-on-our-uk-visa-application/)

> mistakes can lead to misery so getting it correct first time is a must and imperative as first impressions do make all the difference, an application with no mistakes looks better than one with plenty.

So, if it's one letter wrong, I'd suggest using a pen to neatly correctly - **but make sure it is clear.**

If the mistake is much bigger, I would print a new form and start again.

Answer (score 2):

[The consensus on the internet](http://www.immigrationboards.com/uk-tier-4-student-visas/mistake-in-online-uk-visa-application-t106987.html) seems to be that [you can make corrections to a paper UK visa application form](http://www.immigrationboards.com/uk-tier-4-student-visas/uk-student-visitor-visa-application-submitted-with-error-t105553.html). Obviously you'll want to **keep the correction as neat as possible**, making sure that the correct information is readable and the incorrect one is clearly crossed out. If in doubt, I would advise you to get a new form and start over.