# Clerical mistake in UK visa application: should I make a pen-and-ink correction or electronically edit the PDF?

Tags: visas

I've gone through all similar questions but I believe my specific question doesn't have an answer yet.

I've applied for a Standard Visitor visa. After I completed the application, made an appointment and paid the fee, I noticed that the way I spelled my name on the application differs from how it is spelled in the passport by 1 letter (this is partially because of myself being an idiot, but mainly because my new passport has an incorrect transliteration of my name, whereas my old passport and any other document in my life has the correct one).

So here are the options I see:

- Print the application and make a pen-and-ink correction with a black ballpoint pen by crossing the printed name/letter and writing the correct one - as answers to other similar questions suggests.
- Edit the PDF electronically and print it so that there are no visible corrections. However, as the form is saved at their end, there will be a discrepance between the printed form and saved form with no visible signs of correction.

Which way has better chance for me to have my application accepted?

Also (probably doesn't matter much but still): if it's the pen-and-ink correction, is it better to cross-out the whole name or only the wrong letter?

Comment: I don't know the actual answer to this, but I would reprint the form, correct it by hand, and take it with you to the appointment with your new and old passports and explain the problem to the interviewing officer.

Comment: I would cross the whole name and re write. And I agree with @Midavalo .

Answer (score 3):

> Which way has better chance for me to have my application accepted?

The [recommended way](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68868/making-pen-and-ink-corrections-on-a-uk-visa-form) is to make a pen-and-ink correction and be mindful to point out to the VFS/consulate employee when submitting your application. Correcting the PDF risks leaving your changes unnoticed (as they are also tracked in a database) and jeopardizing your applications outcome.